# Selenium and Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, selenium, laravel-5

I'm getting sad,

I use Laravel 5.2 and I am developping my unit tests.

In Laravel 5.1, you could use the great Integrated lib to use selenium, but it doesn't seem to work in Laravel 5.2

So basically, Is there any kind of integration between L5.2 and Selenium, or is it imposible to use it nicely?

In this case, I should definitively have stayed in L5.1 as testing is a fundamental part of my app :(

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/has-anyone-tried-laravel-integrated-package-in-laravel-52

Answer (score 0):

You need to install PHPUnit_selenium package using composer

```
composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit-selenium
```

Create Selenium Test Case class inside laravel/tests/

```
<?php

class SeleniumTestCase extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{
    /**
     * The base URL to use while testing the application.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->setBrowser('firefox');
        $this->setBrowserUrl('http://localhost:8000/');
    }

    protected function visit($path)
    {
        $this->url($path);
        return $this;
    }

    protected function see($text, $tag = 'body')
    {
        print_r(request()->session()->all());
        //method call by tag name;
        $this->assertContains($text,$this->byTag($tag)->text());
        return $this;
    }

    protected function pressByName($text){
        $this->byName($text)->click();
        return $this;
    }
    protected function pressByTag(){
        $this->byTag('button')->click();
        return $this;
    }
    protected function type($value, $name)
    {
        $this->byName($name)->value($value);
        return $this;
    }

    protected function hold($seconds){
        sleep($seconds);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

and Create new test case for visiting home page url

```
<?php    
class ExampleTest extends SeleniumTestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic functional test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testTitle()
    {
        $this->visit('/')
            ->see('Site title','title');
    }
}
```

and Run command PHPunit test from terminal

```
java -jar /usr/local/bin/selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar
```

Reference document:

- https://gist.github.com/dhavalv/85cd0e8a9a5355543787f882dca0b7cf
- https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2013/09/testing-your-project-with-phpunit-and-selenium/
- https://www.sitepoint.com/using-selenium-with-phpunit/

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.2 and later versions, the Laravel team introduced the Laravel Dusk package specifically for browser testing using Selenium. Dusk provides an expressive, fluent interface for interacting with your application using browser automation.

To use Dusk in Laravel 5.2 for Selenium testing, you can follow these steps:

1. install dusk:

```
composer require --dev laravel/dusk

php artisan dusk:install
```

In your `tests/DuskTestCase.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Laravel\Dusk\TestCase as BaseTestCase;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions;

abstract class DuskTestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;

    protected function driver()
    {
        $options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments([
            // Add any additional options here
        ]);

        return \Dusk\Chrome\ChromeDriver::create(
            'http://localhost:9515', null, $options
        );
    }
}
```

You can now create Dusk tests in the tests/Browser directory. For example:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Browser;

use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;
use Tests\DuskTestCase;

class ExampleTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    public function testBasicExample()
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser->visit('/')
                    ->assertSee('Laravel');
        });
    }
}
```

and for run use: `php artisan dusk`