# How to test the result of a div clicked with Laravel? (Phpunit)

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I have the next div ->

```
<div id="grid">
  <div id="grid-item" onClick="sendServer(1)">Data 1 </div>
  <div id="grid-item" onClick="sendServer(2)">Data 2 </div>
  <div id="grid-item" onClick="sendServer(3)">Data 3 </div>

</div>
```

sendServer() is an ajax that validate and send datas to the server and go to route '`/irCurso{id}`'.

I want to test the result when those div has clicked, I know that I can't use `->click()` method be cause it just works with `<a>` tag. This is my code :

```
$this->visit('/cursos')
            ->click('id=grid-item')
            ->seePage('irCurso/1');
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Good question. If you were to consider something like `codeception`,  you could easily do `click('#grid-item')` or `click('.grid-item')`. Also you can resort to `xpath` when attributes, classes and ids aren't enough. Unfortunately the learning curve isn't too pleasant.

Comment: [You should avoid using same id multiple times in one html document](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/127180/72522) (I mean `id="grid-item"`)

Comment: Almost 1 year later, no answer?

Answer (score 0):

As Artenes Nogueira mentioned, Laravel 5.3 and earlier version does not have browser test support.

In order to solve this problem, You need to install PHPUnit_selenium package using composer

`composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit-selenium`

Create Selenium Test Case class inside `tests` folder

```
<?php


class SeleniumTestCase extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{
    /**
     * The base URL to use while testing the application.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->setBrowser('firefox');
        $this->setBrowserUrl('http://localhost:8000/');
    }

    protected function visit($path)
    {
        $this->url($path);
        return $this;
    }

    protected function see($text, $tag = 'body')
    {
        print_r(request()->session()->all());
        //method call by tag name;
        $this->assertContains($text,$this->byTag($tag)->text());
        return $this;
    }

    protected function pressByName($text){
        $this->byName($text)->click();
        return $this;
    }
    protected function pressByTag(){
        $this->byTag('button')->click();
        return $this;
    }
    protected function type($value, $name)
    {
        $this->byName($name)->value($value);
        return $this;
    }

    protected function hold($seconds){
        sleep($seconds);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

and Create new test case for visiting homepage URL

```
<?php    

class ExampleTest extends SeleniumTestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic functional test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testTitle()
    {
        $this->visit('/')
            ->see('Site title','title');
    }
}
```

and Before starting any test you need to start selenium server

```
java -jar /usr/local/bin/selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar
```

Finally, Run command PHPUnit test from terminal

Happy Testing!

References:

[Selenium and Laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35856675/selenium-and-laravel-5-2)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using 5.3 or lower it is not possible to test the result of a div clicked by the Laravel test API.

When you click in your div, you expect to run a JS function. Unfortunately Laravel test API will not interpratate your js, so it will not be executed. And since it is not executed, there are not results to be evaluated.

But with Dusk (in laravel 5.4) you are able to test javascript through the Laravel test API. Check out the docs for more info about Dusk: https://laravel.com/docs/master/dusk

Comment: It would be better to answer how to actually solve the problem, instead of saying there is a way to solve it.