# PHPUnit Selenium integration for Laravel 5.2+

Tags: php, laravel, selenium, phpunit

Before Laravel's 5.2 release, Laracasts' integrated package was providing Selenium integration for Laravel. I couldn't find any similar package for the 5.2 release. Is there any? How can I integrate selenium testing with Laravel?

I've seen these links, they do not provide any solutions:
[Selenium and Laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35856675/selenium-and-laravel-5-2)
[Has anyone tried Laravel Integrated package in Laravel 5.2?](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/has-anyone-tried-laravel-integrated-package-in-laravel-52)

Comment: Check this out ;) https://github.com/Kyslik/asos-selenium/tree/master/application its step by step. You can easily deduct how to us it within Laravel scope.

Comment: yeah i know i can use webdriver with phpunit. but i wanted an integration package like laracasts' integrated. thank for the link though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHPUnit itself has a [selenium extension](https://phpunit.de/manual/5.7/en/index.html). It's not quite laravelish, and is not backed by a modern WebDriver interface.

[CodeCeption](http://codeception.com/) is a very powerful, yet easy-to-use testing tool for PHP. Not only does it provide a unit-testing API, it also provides its own selenium [acceptance testing API](http://codeception.com/docs/03-AcceptanceTests).

It also has perfect [Laravel integration](http://codeception.com/for/laravel) and a great [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/codeception-testtools/jhaegbojocomemkcnmnpmoobbmnkijik) for generating acceptance test in browser. Here's an example code from the docs:

```
<?php
$I->amOnPage('/login');
$I->fillField('username', 'davert');
$I->fillField('password', 'qwerty');
$I->click('LOGIN');
$I->see('Welcome to codeception!');
```

Here's a step-by-step guide to getting started with acceptance testing using CodeCeption:
http://codeception.com/11-20-2013/webdriver-tests-with-codeception.html

Here are some other options:
https://github.com/lmc-eu/steward
https://github.com/Modelizer/Selenium
https://github.com/jhoopes/laravel-selenium-driver

**Update**: [Good news](https://twitter.com/taylorotwell/status/803629579373903873).
**Update**: See [Mink's PHPUnit integration](https://phpunit-mink.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).